# How to put a XSLT tag in an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, xslt

I have set a XSLT variable "description" with a "meta_words" namespace in a meta description HTML tag.

Do you have the solution?

Here is the code wrong

```
<meta name="description" content="<xsl:value-of match="meta_words" select="$description" />" />
```

Comment: Escape the content of the attribute or it won't be valid.

Comment: The attribute 'match' is not valid on xsl:value-of. Can you show exactly what your 'description' variable is set to, to make it clearer? Thanks!

Comment: He went through PHP like this
`XSLTProcessor::setParameter('meta_words', 'description', 'My meta description, ....');`

Answer (score 4):

> Here is the code wrong
>
> ```
> <meta name="description" content="<xsl:value-of match="meta_words" select="$description" />" />
> ```

Indeed, this is wrong. The `xsl:value-of` instruction doesn't have a `match` attribute -- so it isn't clear waht you actually want to do and what the result should look like.

Here is what I *guess* you want.

**Use**:

```
<meta name="description" content="{$description}"/>
```

**Update**:

From a comment made by the OP it seems that there is a parameter named `$meta_words:description` -- not a param/variable named `$description`.

In this case the solution above must be modified to:

```
<meta name="description" content="{$meta_words:description}"/>
```

and the correct namespace definition for the prefix `"meta_words"` must be in scope (one usually puts such namespace definitions on the `xsl:stylesheet` element).

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:meta_words="some:meta_words" exclude-result-prefixes="meta_words">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="meta_words:description" select="'XYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <meta name="description" content="{$meta_words:description}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used for this demo), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<meta name="description" content="XYZ"/>
```

Comment: Yes, but where can I put the namespace

Comment: What namespace? The question in its present form doesn't show the wanted result at all -- so we cannot guess what namespaces, if any, are wanted to be generated. Please, *edit* the question and provide all missing and important information.

Comment: If you want to access a parameter in the namespace `meta_words` then use put `xmlns:metaw="meta_words"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element and then use `<meta name="description" content="{$metaw:description}"/>` in the attribute value template.